# Where is the data saved on Submit action in Sitecore Forms?

Tags: sitecore-forms

For a form if the submit Action is set to "Save Data", I would like to see where the data is saved after a user submit a form. 
After exporting data to CSV files, i can view data but still do not know where i can see data in Sitecore.

I also tried to find in [Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms?roles=all) but wasn't able to find any information.

Comment: are you using Sitecore 9 forms or wffm ?

Comment: Also what version of Sitecore are you using and are you using xDB?

Comment: @VladIobagiu I am using Sitecore 9 Forms

Comment: @AdamSeabridge sitecore verion 9.0.1. I am. I am not using xDB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot see data directly in Sitecore (except of exporting them to CSV file).

You can see stored data in SQL Server in sitecoreInstanceName_ExperienceForms database.

There are two tables:

1. FieldData - Here you can see actual posted data with there field name, value and field type
2. FormEntry - Here you can find relationship between FieldData and FormId